# Uncaught (in promise) Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

Hey I am new here in Flutter. I have one app already build on Flutter and I need to create a web with existing one. The app is using Firebase so I am using `firebase_core_web` but when I run the app I got the below error in my Flutter Web Console.

```
errors.dart:266 Uncaught (in promise) Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:266:49)
    at [dartx._get] (js_array.dart:581:7)
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.callMethod (operations.dart:398:10)
    at Object.dsend (operations.dart:402:5)
    at [_getTaskName] (dio_client.dart:345:53)
    at [_endProgress] (dio_client.dart:107:24)
    at dio_client.DioClient.new.getUri (dio_client.dart:101:7)
    at getUri.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at dio_client.DioClient.new.getUri (dio_client.dart:75:25)
    at laravel_provider.LaravelApiClient.new.getSettings (laravel_provider.dart:1319:38)
    at getSettings.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at laravel_provider.LaravelApiClient.new.getSettings (laravel_provider.dart:1316:30)
    at setting_repository.SettingRepository.new.get (setting_repository.dart:15:30)
    at settings_service.SettingsService.new.init (settings_service.dart:29:41)
    at init.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at settings_service.SettingsService.new.init (settings_service.dart:25:31)
    at main.dart:35:46
    at GetInstance.putAsync (get_instance.dart:62:32)
    at putAsync.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at GetInstance.putAsync (get_instance.dart:57:24)
    at Inst$124putAsync (extension_instance.dart:43:21)
    at Inst$124putAsync.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at Object.Inst$124putAsync [as Inst|putAsync] (extension_instance.dart:41:24)
    at initServices (main.dart:35:13)
    at initServices.next (<anonymous>)
    at async_patch.dart:45:50
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1653:54)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:147:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:766:44)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:795:13)
    at [_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:566:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:639:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
```

Can anyone help me with this that how can I solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post your code where this error appears.

Comment: Actually the code is running properly with Android but making issue while converting to Web and I myself dont know from where it may be coming. I know I have to check count but of which I wont be able to understand.